# An apparent dichotomy in the calculation of a limit with indeterminacy $ 0^0 $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}(x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5)^\frac{1}{\log(4x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4)}$$

Comment: The answer you posted should not be an answer, it should instead be part of the question, representing [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) that is an important part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

By taking logarithms on both members we got
$$\log L= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5)}{\log(4x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4)},$$
which is of the indeterminate form $\infty/\infty$. By applying successively L'Hôpital's rule, I got $L=e^{5/4}$ as result. However correct is $L=e$. I was unable to find my mistake. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I apologize for my trivial mistake.Thinking in that successive derivatives involved in L'Hôpital's rule, leading terms are those ones with greatest order, i.e. $25x^8/20x^8=5/4$. Wrong! On the contrary the important terms are the minor ones, i.e. $(x\cdot4)/(4x\cdot1)=1$, and all the remaining terms containing powers of $x>1$ disappear as $x\to0$. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}(x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5)^\frac{1}{\log(4x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4)}=\lim_{x \to 0}e^{\log{\Big[(x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5)^\frac{1}{\log(4x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4)}}\Big]}=\lim_{x \to 0}e^{\frac{\log{(x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5)}}{\log(4x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4)}}=\lim_{x \to 0}e^{\frac{\log{[x(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4)]}}{\log[x(4+3x+2x^2+x^3)]}}=\lim_{x \to 0}e^{\frac{\log{[x]}}{\log[4x]}}=e$$.
The last equality can be obtained thinking about the Hospital rule for which we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log{x}}{\log{4x}}=\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}=1$$.

$\textbf{For your mistake remember:}$
if you are dealing with the limit of $x$ goes to $0$, consider the "slower" terms (therefore of a lower degree) that you can find in the numerator and denominator and "leave out" the others}, in effect this is exaclty what you obtain selecting $x$ both at numerator and denominator in the last but one passage.